# Need to decrease 1 from span classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are multiple spans class in the following div boxes. I need to change the class of span.

```html
<div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
  The class of div is same
  <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> Need one with worker <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> allocation to work
  <span class="ing-tag_1"> The data not to be changed </span>
   <span class="ing-tag_2"> The data not to be changed </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_3"> The data not to be changed </span>
</div>
<div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
  This one has same class of span
  <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> only
  <span class="ing-tag_1"> The data to be changed </span>more data is here and this is all giberish  <span class="ing-tag_3"> The  changed </span> and <span class="ing-tag_4"> The data to be changed </span> cloth manufacturing erp <span class="ing-tag_5"> The data to be changed </span>. Need  <span class="ing-tag_6"> The data not to be changed </span>one with worker  allocation to work
</div>
<div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
  <span class="ing-tag_0"> qweq </span> Need one with worker allocation to work <span class="ing-tag_0"> qweq </span>
   <span class="ing-tag_5"> qweq </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_6"> qweq </span>
     <span class="ing-tag_7"> qweq </span>
</div>
```

I need that if I need to decrease 1 from the tag class. for example `ing-tag_1` becomes `ing-tag_0`,`ing-tag_2` becomes `ing-tag_1` till the maximum one.

This need to be done from a index. For example if I get index 4 and the maximum span class has 7.

Then starting from `ing-tag_4` to `ing-tag_7`. The `ing-tag_5` becomes `ing-tag_5`,  `ing-tag_6` becomes `ing-tag_5`, `ing-tag_7` becomes `ing-tag_6` and  `ing-tag_4` becomes `ing-tag_missing`.And also need to remove the span for missing ing-tag_4. The one which are inside step_input class or show a missing.

So far I have tried

```
document.querySelectorAll('.step_input > .ing-tag_'+4).forEach(e => e.id = e.id-1 );
```

Comment: Read it again like you read a question that someone else asked and say if you understand what is going on there...

Comment: I feel like you are putting too much logic into your class names.  Refactoring to use a data-* element would probably be very benificial.

Comment: @j08691 Added the tried section

Comment: @Dekel I have edited my question to enhance readability

Comment: I really don't understand what you trying to accomplish there. You explain what you think your code should do, but not what the final outcome should be.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want, and doesn't rely on specific positioning of the class name, since other classes can be added.

Note that it assumes there's only one class per element in the format you require.

However, using classes for this isn't great. A `data-` attribute seems like it would be better.

```js
var re = /ing-tag_(\d+)/;

function decrement(idx) {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.step_input > span[class*=ing-tag_]');

  for (const span of spans) {
    // Use replace with a callback to get the captured index number
    span.className = span.className.replace(re, function(m, g1) {
      if (+g1 < idx) { // Below the index, don't change anything
        return m;
      }
      if (+g1 === idx) { // Equal index, add "missing"
        return "ing-tag_missing";
      }
      return "ing-tag_" + (+g1 - 1); // Above the index, decrement
    });
  }
}

decrement(4);

console.log(document.body.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
    The class of div is same
    <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> Need one with worker <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> allocation to work
    <span class="ing-tag_1"> The data not to be changed </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_2"> The data not to be changed </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_3"> The data not to be changed </span>
  </div>
  <div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
    This one has same class of span
    <span class="ing-tag_0"> The data to be changed </span> only
    <span class="ing-tag_1"> The data to be changed </span>more data is here and this is all giberish
    <span class="ing-tag_3"> The  changed </span> and
    <span class="ing-tag_4"> The data to be changed </span> cloth manufacturing erp
    <span class="ing-tag_5"> The data to be changed </span>. Need <span class="ing-tag_6"> The data not to be changed </span>one with worker allocation to work
  </div>
  <div class="step_input" contenteditable="true">
    <span class="ing-tag_0"> qweq </span> Need one with worker allocation to work
    <span class="ing-tag_0"> qweq </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_5"> qweq </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_6"> qweq </span>
    <span class="ing-tag_7"> qweq </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am developing this on meteor. Please if you have any better solution for this. @spanky

Comment: Please suggest how can I implement using data-*

Comment: A `data-` attribute is just a regular HTML attribute that starts with `data-`. This lets you keep the data associated with an element separate from classes, which are commonly used for other purposes. So instead of `<span class="ing-tag_7">`, you could do `<span class="ing-tag" data-index="7">`. Then the data is accessed as `element.dataset.index`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

Get all of the `span` elements:

```
var spanAll = document.querySelectorAll('span');
```

Get each span's class number:

```
var spanClassNumberAll = [...spanAll].map(function(s){
  return s.className[s.className.length -1];
});
```

Determine maximum number:

```
var maxVal = Math.max(...spanClassNumberAll);
```

Return all of the elements that fall into the range of the index and maxVal:

```
var indexVal = '4';
var matches = [...spanAll].filter(function(el){
  var thisNumVal = el.className[el.className.length -1];
  return thisNumVal >= indexVal && thisNumVal <= maxVal;
});
```

Subtract from each span's className

```
matches.forEach(function(s){
  var thisNumVal = s.className[s.className.length -1];
  var newNumVal = thisNumVal - "1";
  if(thisNumVal == indexVal){
    newNumVal = 'missing';
  }
  //concatenate new className
  //split the className by underscore(_)
  s.className = s.className.split('_')[0] + '_' + newNumVal;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3uuent7g/1/)